# Button to replace another button depending on PHP queries

Tags: php

I need a button to replace another button depending on several `PHP if statements`. The way it works is that, a user can `favourite` another user only once, if a user is already favourited, it will display another button rather than the default set of buttons which are available to a non favourited user.

I have a table in my database called `favourites`. I have inserted one row for testing.

```
id - 16
favourited_who - Freddy
favourited_by - AliceP
```

Just for reference, my site at the moment has three users: `AliceP`, `Freddy` and `Fred`. Just to explain, I am logged in as `AliceP` and and as you can see `Fred` is not in my `favourites`, in that case two buttons should be displayed for `Fred` which are `Send Message` and `Add to Favourites`. On the other hand, `Freddy` is in my favourites, in which case I want to display two buttons, which are `Send Message` and `Remove from Favourites`.

With the following code below, the `Remove from Favourites` button is being shown for both `Fred` and `Freddy`, when it shouldn't.

I need the three conditions to be covered in my code, which I believe I have:

```
// 1. Con 1: Dont display any buttons for the logged in user as they cannot fav or msg themselves.
// 2. Con 2: Display sendmsg and addfriend btn if the user is not in the logged in users favs
// 3. Con 3: Display sendmsg and remfriend btn is the user is in the logged in users favs.
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
if (isset($_POST['addfriend'])) { 
    $fav_request    = $_POST['addfriend'];
    $favourited_who = $user; // u variable
    $favourited_by  = $username; // logged in user

    // Get all the favourites of the logged in user...
    $q = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE favourited_by='$username'");
    $num_of_favs = mysqli_num_rows($q);
        $r_query = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
            $db_fav_who = $r_query['favourited_who'];
            $db_fav_by = $r_query['favourited_by'];

    // Check: See if $user isn't already in there favourites.
    /*if ($db_fav_by == $username){ // if logged in user has anyone favourited
        // if the user already exists in the logged in users favourites, then display remove from favourites button.
        if ($db_fav_who == $user){
            echo "<div class='edit_profile'> 
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='remfriend' value='Remove from Favourites'>
            </div>";
            }
        }*/
        //}// while loop closed
    if ($user != $username) { // Check: See user isnt favouriting themself.
        $favourite_user = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO favourites VALUES ('', '$favourited_who', '$favourited_by')");
    }
} // if isset closed

// Condition 1:
if ($user == $username){
      // dont display buttons     
} 
// Condition 2:
if ($user != $username && $favourited_who != $db_fav_who){ // if $user is not equal to db fav_who value
    echo "<form method='post'>
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='sendmsg' value='Send Message'/>
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='addfriend' value='Add to Favourites'>
              </form>";
    }     
// Condition 3:
if ($user != $username && $favourited_who == $db_fav_who) { 
        echo "<form method='post'>
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='sendmsg' value='Send Message'/>
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='remfriend' value='Remove from Favourites'>
              </form>";
        }
```

I have covered all three conditions but I am unable to understand why the code does not show the correct button for each scenario?

**Edit:**

Found the solution, turns out I had to add the following outside the `if isset` closed brace:

```
   $favourited_who = $user; // u variable
    $favourited_by  = $username; // logged in user
    // Get all the favourites of the logged in user...
    $q = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE favourited_by='$username'");
    $num_of_favs = mysqli_num_rows($q);
        $r_query = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
            $db_fav_who = $r_query['favourited_who'];
            $db_fav_by = $r_query['favourited_by'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a

```
<form method='post'>
```

for the following line?

```
            echo "<div class='edit_profile'> 
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='remfriend' value='Remove from Favourites'>
        </div>";
```

The other  have them.

Comment: Well the `if statement` leading to that echo is similar to the code found under `//condition 3`. Nevertheless, I want the `<input>` to replace `addfriend` button input from condition 2, which is surrounded by `form` tags.

Comment: Feddy, this is only a guess!, but in the previous if statement the values of $db_fav_who and favourited_who are set to the same value. In the following line. $db_fav_who = $r_query['favourited_who']; so when the proceeding if statement runs they will match and the 3rd condition is met. Is that right or am I missing something?

Comment: The first time i assign a value to `$db_fav_who` is with the line ` $db_fav_who = $r_query['favourited_who'];` which is getting the data from the database for the column labelled "favourited_who". I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You write **while loop closed** but where is loop???

may be

```
while($r_query = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) { ... };
```

Also you comment one`{` and two `}` in this code

```
  /*  if ($db_fav_who == $user){
        echo "<div class='edit_profile'> 
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='remfriend' value='Remove from Favourites'>
        </div>";
        }
    }*/
```

Comment: I initially did have a while loop, it was `while ($r_query = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) { ... }`, but I later removed the while loop, and commented out the closing tag.

Comment: One `}` closes the while loop (which I have removed). Another `}` closes this if statement `if ($db_fav_who == $user){` and the last `}` closes this if statement `if ($db_fav_by == $username){`.